# Decline further reputation from votes on an answer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers

I'm embarrassed by how many upvotes my (not that good, as the discussion thread will show) answer to [Why are variables "i" and "j" used for counters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters) has gotten.  Is there a way I could decline to receive any further positive reputation from that answer?

(That particular question seems to have been marked "community wiki" since the last time I looked at it, which I *think* means nobody gets any reputation from answer votes anymore, but before that happened, that one answer caused me to hit the reputation cap twice; and I'd still like a way to decline further reputation from an answer without affecting the entire question.)

Comment: I say take the all the rep you get. Because there will be plenty of answers that you will give that are concise, insightful, and dead-on-balls accurate and you won't get nearly the rep you should.

Comment: As @Al points out, take the rep - you are earning it. There is a balance where your answer(s) will not receive the rep that you *should* get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already do this by manually converting your answer to community-wiki mode.

This can be done at any time by editing the answer, clicking the "community wiki" checkbox, and submitting. Once this is done, you will no longer receive or lose reputation for the answer (except bounties).

Be aware, however, that **this operation cannot be undone**. You will also continue to receive badges for the answer as applicable (this cannot be disabled).

Comment: @Hans No, Community Wiki is fully possible on answers, as that is where it is most appropriate.

Comment: @Hans: The CW UI element was removed for *questions* only, not answers.

Comment: Ah yes, I realized.  Y'all are quick.