# Revise the community wiki policy, or enforce it better

Tags: discussion, feature-request, policy

I say "or" in the title because I've not read the exact policy. My concern is with the implementation of whatever policy is in place. It feels very reminiscent of a socialist government. When a great invention is created the innovator isn't regarded as having created a success which they can then profit from (ie, rep points), but rather is regarded as having stumbled into something way to important to patent (ie, the government steals the invention and says, "It's for the greater good").

My point is, if a question is truly a question as in the case of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters), credit should not be taken by the community for the question. The user should get full credit for all points and should remain the author of the question. Users with high rep can already edit other questions, so the contribution aspect is a moot point in this argument. This policy (or perhaps misunderstanding of a correct policy) of stripping attribution and rep points is like reverse Darwinism.

Comment: So...you want to revise something you haven't read?

Comment: I disagree with this post, although I haven't actually read past the first line yet

Comment: For the record, that question was turned Community Wiki for gaining over 30 answers, not by some kind of secret police. Perchance there is room for change in that rule, but it would've done you better to at least research this a little first before coming with accusations about bad policies as if people were intentionally targetting "innovation".

Comment: +1 Glenn Beck taught me to hate socialism

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741 which explains the rules for CW posts

Comment: @Rebecca - if I go into a store and the cashiers are giving the customers everything for free, I don't need to read the employee manual to know something is wrong.

Comment: Actually on the question you referenced, that wasn't a programming question, that was an historical question, so it doesn't belong on SO in the first place.  Hopefully when Programmers gets out of Beta they'll move it over there.

Comment: @Lance - So, it should be on `the-history-of-programming.stackexchange.com`? `Programmers` is not for the history of code.

Comment: @Lance That's... somewhat irrelevant to it turning Community Wiki. Nor would it revert that, anyway. Topicality and accessibility-of-editing are rather independent of each other, with good reason.

Comment: @Nick T - Thanks. And, I'm very happy for that, but I have to ask why it took an idiot commentator / radio show host to finally convince you that power corrupts, and the federal government (of any country) is likely the cause of all the country's real problems. (I really just felt like getting all of that off my shoulders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode."

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)

Comment: @Dan - but not any votes that occur after that

Comment: @orokausaki ~ and yet it wasn't your question that got CWd. What exactly is your point? That you don't like the way SO is run? We all seem to like it just fine.

Comment: @Orokusaki ~ Fortunately for me you do read profiles, so that proves that I can trust that you don't normally resort to ad-hominem attacks. Therefore I can trust that your car runs on unleaded gasoline. ~ See what I did there? My point was, the policy is that CW will occur at some point.

Comment: `hasn't taught you to think for yourself yet`... not ad hominem? (by the way, ad hominem is not hyphenated. See what I did just there? I've educated you on one of the fallacies. By the way, I live on an Awamba Lagoon and have no car as most of my days are spent in a 50 foot by 30 foot space in Boracay (thus not requiring a car). On another note (whilst I'm educating you), they haven't used leaded gasoline in civilization since the mid 70s, so it's not necessary to add the `unleaded` part. That's just another sign for me to better understand your predicament. I'm off to breakfast now.

Comment: @drachenstern - forgot the @you in my last comment.

Comment: @orokusaki ~ A) ad-hominem vs ad hominem: whatever. B) I have no clue where Awamba Lagoon is and I don't know why you brag about living in a single room. Most of the world calls that prison. C) the leaded gasoline thing was rather my point, a useless argument. D) `but I have to ask why it took an idiot commentator / radio show host to finally convince you that power corrupts` you started it sir. Did you forget that?

Comment: @drachenstern - A) ok, moot, B) It's a 50 foot catamaran sail boat which of course is a lie since I live in a house and drive a car and only wish I sailed in Boracay on a daily basis (I said that because the "leaded gasoline" bit isn't ad hominem. It's "Ignoratio Elenchi" or "The Red Herring" - another fallacy altogether), C) ok, moot, and finally D) I up-voted his comment. The `idiot commentator...` was meant to be cynical, not ad hominem.

Comment: I knew that neither one was ad hominem, your attack on me was, and I never said what either of those were in particular. I just was pointing out my jab was tit-for-tat with yours. I see we agree now and that we have gotten all that out of our systems. :p Shall I buy you a beer next time we are in the same general locale? I'm easy enough to track down ;) Cheers mate. Here's to living on a Awamba Lagoon 16 hours a day in the future (I google too ;) )

Comment: @drachenstern - sounds good to me... and "truce". I do resort to Giulianish tactics.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287893?tab=reputation) for the author of the question you will see the poster was awarded a total of **541** reputation for that question.

Looking at the [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520?tab=reputation) of the highest voting answer we see that they recieved a total of **1523** reputation for their answer.

This is a truly **absurd** amount of reputation to gain from a single post - the author of the answer even [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71657/decline-further-reputation-from-votes-on-an-answer) that he not receive any more rep from that answer.

---

(I'm pretty sure that the reputation graph accounts for losses due to reaching the daily rep cap)

Comment: Crepes, 541 reputation is higher than anything I've ever earned on *answers*.

Comment: Maybe God's own technical answer *should* develop 500 rep. But the question in question is certainly not 500 rep worth of "helpful". But then, *my* best answer netted nearly 500 points and I didn't think is was that hot (don't get me wrong, I was proud of it, but 465 rep?!?)